# .htaccess redirect - automatically add www. if no subdomain exists

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I need any www. added automatically to my domain ONLY IF a subdomain is not already there.  I do want subdomains to bypass this redirect.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To automatically add a `www` to your domain name when there isn't a subdomain, add this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you.  This seems to work.  Can you explain why the previous one didn't work in your opinion?  I noticed it working; however, then noticed that my subdomain didnt work.  Not sure if this was related or not or just propagation issues.  I would love to learn more about what each line means of the 2 answers.  Thanks!

Comment: @kdjernigan the `www` was never added to the redirect, and the first condition matches a subdomain.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work unless it's at the top of my .htaccess file... which is fine. Just strange.

Comment: Does this solution assume a TLD with only one dot? i.e. it won't work for `.co.uk`?

Comment: its checking only one dot in TLD to make it work with .co.uk you need to check two dots here is my quick solution RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$ just change this condition rest remain same

Comment: TLD assumption aside, how does it know the difference between www and a subdomain? Don't they look the same to the regex?

Comment: @LWC the regex is only checking the domain and TLD, it won't know the difference between a "www" or any other subdomain. Thus if there is a subdomain, or a "www", the condition fails and the rule is skipped.

Comment: does not work on apache 2.4 - it results in: `www.sub.domain.com`