# redirect "non-www" domain to "www"domain with .htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I couldn't find the solution for "non-www" to "www" domain redirection. I have tried the following :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

**So, how can I redirect**, for example  `domain.com` or `www.domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com` ?.

Comment: can anyone explain me the reason for down vote.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess

Comment: @aldanux I have gone throught before, but it doesn't helped me.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx

Answer (score 0):

Something like should work :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what should help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

[How To Create Temporary and Permanent Redirects with Apache click hear](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx)

**To automatically add a www to your domain name:**

```
  RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or

> .htaccess To Redirect URLs

**To use htaccess to redirect URL just copy and paste the snippet below and replace example.com with your domain.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

[More info true ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256130/htaccess-redirect-automatically-add-www-if-no-subdomain-exists)

[Redirecting non-www to www with .htaccess](http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/)

Comment: it isn't redirecting, says `The page isn't redirecting properly`

Comment: this one add on top of htaccess.

Comment: did the same, but no use!
Do i need to do any edit on httpd file??

Comment: none is working, may be there is a problem on my domain registrar.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: have tried this before but it isn't redirecting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems apache mod_rewrite module is not enabled. So Make sure the Apache module mod_rewrite is enabled on your web server.

Comment: Everything that i gave on my htaccess is working other than this www part. Btw i am sure mod_rewrite module is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try again this and see..It must work.

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

See here - http://iyngaran.info, It is working. So no problem with the rule