# How to put "www" in front of my domain in simple html based website.?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a website named [**redpeppermedia.in**](http://redpeppermedia.in) and I wish to see it's url as **www.redpeppermedia.in** instead of *redpeppermedia.in*

Do you have any idea how to do it? It's a simple website, I'm not using wordpress or drupal or any sort of website creation tool.

Thank You..

Comment: htaccess might do the trick

Comment: see - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Comment: this is to do with webserver, and jquery won't help you. Do you know if you use apache or nginx? And do you have permission to change its setting?

Comment: Yes I did change the .htaccess file, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add file `.htaccess` to your website's root, then add the the following lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.redpeppermedia.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.redpeppermedia.in/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes I did put this code in the .htaccess file, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write in your .htaccess file the mod rewrite to automatically setup the 'www' if the subdomain not exists. Just can see other examples

[.htaccess redirect - automatically add www. if no subdomain exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256130/htaccess-redirect-automatically-add-www-if-no-subdomain-exists)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can check the 'mod rewrite' extension in the Apache foundation oficial website.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html