# Site access via www.example.com v. example.com is causing problems with sessions

Tags: session, web, url

I have a site at GoDaddy.  You may access it using a www prefix or not.  It works fine either way unless you happen to hit a link that uses/does not use the prefix.  Then the session disappears.  Is www.example.com supposed to be the same as example.com?  If not, how do I require the use of one or the other?

Comment: Do you have access to htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are based on cookies, and cookies are bound to a specific domain. www.abc.com is a subdomain of abc.com (In some cases, you might not even be the owner of both).

I would force webserver to add a www prefix (with .htaccess if you are using Apache: [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256130/htaccess-redirect-automatically-add-www-if-no-subdomain-exists))

Comment: Thanks for the link.