# using .htaccess to add www prefix

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site hosted on godaddy. uses apache.
I used this code in .htaccess to add www prefix to the domain automatically

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/../$1 [R=301,L]
```

but instead of 'www.example.com' it goes to 'www.example.com/web'

I just want to convert 'example.com' to 'www.example.com'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect - automatically add www. if no subdomain exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256130/htaccess-redirect-automatically-add-www-if-no-subdomain-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/web/$ http://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert `example.com` to `www.example.com` then you just need to use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

You can also lay it out like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this. You will notice I've just the flag `R=302`. This is a temporary redirect, use this while you're testing. If you're happy with the `RewriteRule` and everything is working, change these to `R=301`, which is a permanent redirect.